# How do I select records that are older than 5 minutes from oracle using unix dates/times

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, time

I am trying to bring back records that are older than 5 minutes from the current time. Here is what I have so far, but it seems to bring back all the records not just ones which are older than 5 minutes:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "DOCUMENT_QUEUE"."DOCUMENT_NUMBER") as "Records" 
FROM   "MAGINUS"."DOCUMENT_QUEUE" "DOCUMENT_QUEUE"
WHERE  to_date('01-JAN-1970', 'dd-MON-yyyy HH:MI:SS') + (DOCUMENT_QUEUE.CREATION_DATE/86400) > sysdate - 38/1440
ORDER BY "DOCUMENT_QUEUE"."DOCUMENT_NUMBER"
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [interval literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-DC8D1DAD-7D04-45EA-9546-82810CD09A1B):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "DOCUMENT_QUEUE"."DOCUMENT_NUMBER") as "Records" 
FROM   "MAGINUS"."DOCUMENT_QUEUE" "DOCUMENT_QUEUE"
WHERE  DOCUMENT_QUEUE.CREATION_DATE < SYSDATE - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
ORDER BY "DOCUMENT_QUEUE"."DOCUMENT_NUMBER";
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "DOCUMENT_QUEUE"."DOCUMENT_NUMBER") as "Records" 
FROM   "MAGINUS"."DOCUMENT_QUEUE" "DOCUMENT_QUEUE"
WHERE  round(to_number(DOCUMENT_QUEUE.CREATION_DATE-sysdate)*1440) > 15
ORDER BY "DOCUMENT_QUEUE"."DOCUMENT_NUMBER"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `NOW()` and  `(date_to_unix_ts(DOCUMENT_QUEUE.CREATION_DATE) - 86400 )` for defining range.

Comment: Ankit - those are MySQL functions; Oracle doesn't support them.